# Embedding Form Filter on Multiple Fields

Tags: forms, search, filter, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to create a search on two related tables on multiple fields.

I'm embedding the form filters everything renders fine. When I'm trying to validate the form(s), the form fails to execute getName().

I've read some articles about this and one of the tips was to override the addFieldNameColumnQuery() function.

My question is: Is this the only/best way to do it? Should I override a function for every field in the embedded form?

Comment: Can you update this question with the exception you're getting?

Comment: Ok, I've solved it but I forgot to update the article. The way is to create for each embedded form a addFieldNameColumnQuery() . Apparently when you embed a form it you can access it like a field. So .. addFieldNameColumnQuery()  will do the trick for the business logic.